# PHP file not read in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I get the following error:

Warning: chdir() [function.chdir]: No such file or directory (errno 2) in /home/r/workspace/_compiled/APIBase.php on line 288

I can not see the dir it is checking because all the code is encrypted. I do not know another way around it as I have reinstalled and re downloaded twice. Plus I have tried on both XP and Gentoo. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have the source, you will need to contact the vendor for support.

In the future, you should avoid doing business with them without having the complete source code.